# How can I set security to download file in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I don't want guests are able to download files (pdf, word .etc).At first users must log in to download files. How can I get information about it?

Comment: Maybe you can share more information about your current implementation. Your question is very global

Comment: @SNO I want to set security, where users logged as guests, cannot download pdf files, for this they should be sent to login or sign up pages. i searched internet but couldnt find any information about it. Can you help me or give some instructions